# What is the right SQL syntax for this query?

Tags: jquery, sql

I have a table called `Orders` with a column called `OrderId`. I want to run a query that will include order that are

```
OrderId like '123%' or OrderId like '456%'
```

but don't return a row if:

```
OrderId like '123554' or OrderId like '456665%'
```

What is the best way to structure this query as I need to include the top section and do the negative of the result of the bottom section?

Something like

```
Select * 
from Orders 
where (OrderId like '123%' or OrderId like '456%') 
  and not (OrderId like '123554' or OrderId like '456665%')
```

Comment: I would maybe not use a like on the part that is 123554 if it's a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  *
from    orders
where   (orderid like '123%'
     or orderid like '456%')
    and orderid not like '123554%'
    and orderid not like '456665%'
```

Comment: thanks . . do you see anything wrong with the query i have suggested.  I would have expected that to be equivalent to what you have

Comment: @leora the query you put in your edit is fine, what do you mean by "right syntax"?

Comment: oh, I had a typo which was causing the issue.  I can't seem to close the question so i have accepted your owner